# Property 'realtime' does not exist on type 'typeof import

Tags: angular, leaflet

i dont why i have this error when i use

L.realtime(....

**Property 'realtime' does not exist on type 'typeof import....**

extract from Package.json
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
"leaflet-draw": "^1.0.4",
"leaflet-realtime": "^2.2.0",
"leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.0",

```
"@types/leaflet": "^1.7.1",
"@types/leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.4",
```

it works only if i put in the compoment this code

import "node_modules/leaflet-realtime/dist/leaflet-realtime.js"

but with this trick i cant build the project

Comment: `node_modules/leaflet-realtime/dist/leaflet-realtime.js` add this inside your angular.json `script : ['node_modules/leaflet-realtime/dist/leaflet-realtime.js']` array.